# GridView RowDataBound event makes my GridView slow

Tags: vb.net, gridview, modalpopupextender, rowdatabound

I have a PopupExtender that shows some information when a button in the GridView is pressed. This button exists on every row.

I also have a DropDownList present in every row that is populated by querying a database. I do this because it may be populated with different items depending on the row.

The problem I have is that the PopupExtender is slow to pop-up because of the RowDataBound event of the GridView that repopulates the DDLs from the database when the PopupExtender's associated button is pressed.

How can I make the PopUpExtender pop-up faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to consider jQuery Dialog instead of Asp.Net ajax popup extender. 
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/.

Also, do you really need gridview, You can try ListView control instead of GridView.

Comment: I'm looking into jquery dialog now. I will test the ListView but why would it be faster ?

Comment: AJAX Popup extender use postback to open/close the dialog window... jQuery UI will be handling this in client side.

Comment: I require postback to get the information that is shown inside the AJAX Popup. It may be different for each row.

Comment: That is fine, you can use jquery ajax to do a postback and get the content based on the id or what ever parameters and render in jquery ui dialog window. 

for ex: <a href='javscript:openPopup(<DataBind("YOUR FIELD")>'>Open<a> some thing like this.

Comment: On postback will the GridView be rerendered ? Because that is where is the slowness -> Database query for the DDLs in the grid. Generally the grid won't have many items but for 10 items there is a big delay

Comment: if you use jQuery ajax post, it wont rendered gridview again, it will hit only a specific custom method.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to implement this now!